# Changing data frame to sf object in R, so it can be plotted by tmap

Tags: r, dataframe, r-sf, tmap

How can i convert this example dataframe below. So it creates a spatial object that can be plotted by tmap?

The data consists of two Local Authority District (UK) regions - cornwall and hartlepool. It also consists of corresponding metadata that I would like to plot on the map.

```
data <- structure(list(lad19cd = c("E06000001", "E06000052"), objectid = c(1L, 
                                                                           49L), lad19nm = c("Hartlepool", "Cornwall"), bng_e = c(447160L, 
                                                                                                                                  212497L), bng_n = c(531474L, 64493L), long = c(-1.27018, -4.64254
                                                                                                                                  ), lat = c(54.67614, 50.450218), st_areasha = c(93712619.817559, 
                                                                                                                                                                                  3548934061.31533), st_lengths = c(71011.9339493, 1241482.9365225
                                                                                                                                                                                  ), `35 TO 39` = c(16L, 135L), white = c(181L, 848L), Male = c(104L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                492L), `RTB-IBD` = c(155L, 745L), `40 TO 44` = c(25L, 100L), 
                       `45 TO 49` = c(19L, 128L), `Ethnicity Not Stated` = c(54L, 
                                                                             597L), `RTB-GLD` = c(41L, 570L), `16 TO 24` = c(12L, 131L
                                                                             ), `50 TO 54` = c(24L, 138L), `55 TO 59` = c(17L, 143L), 
                       Female = c(132L, 962L), COMPARE = c(34L, 2L), `30 TO 34` = c(21L, 
                                                                                    142L), `>=80` = c(10L, 24L), `65 TO 69` = c(22L, 115L), `60 TO 64` = c(28L, 
                                                                                                                                                           115L), `not stated` = c(1L, 5L), INTERVAL = c(1L, 56L), `70 TO 74` = c(18L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  88L), `RTB-STR` = c(4L, 16L), `25 TO 29` = c(14L, 124L), 
                       `Gender Not Stated` = 2:3, `75 TO 79` = c(12L, 70L), `RTB-INC` = 1:2, 
                       RDC = c(2L, 8L), mixed = c(2L, 4L), `RTB-GEN` = c(NA, 58L
                       ), asian = c(NA, 3L), `<=15` = c(NA, 4L), geometry = structure(list(
                         structure(list(list(structure(c(448986.02, 447072.101, 
                                                         443444.7028, 442588.2966, 440052.7012, 448476.6765, 450118.9667, 
                                                         450132.9512, 454039.03, 451736.05, 452570.529, 448986.02, 
                                                         536729.68, 537135.9959, 533133.0017, 528536.0976, 527819.7026, 
                                                         525831.9601, 525889.424, 525915.536, 528341.61, 532034.85, 
                                                         533906.857, 536729.68), .Dim = c(12L, 2L)))), class = c("XY", 
                                                                                                                 "MULTIPOLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(list(structure(c(234998.8202, 
                                                                                                                                                                          234199.2005, 231675.7996, 226969.1972, 228841.9968, 226421.5025, 
                                                                                                                                                                          221174.0748, 219693.78, 220379.35, 219444.56, 214460.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                          212656.93, 209007, 205248, 204039, 202073.6, 192911.3, 
                                                                                                                                                                          189055.445, 185723.3, 184224.4, 175678.578, 175640.08, 
                                                                                                                                                                          172566.344, 169790.439, 168442.779, 163047.156, 158149.197, 
                                                                                                                                                                          154807.334, 150551.418, 147582.929, 143206.63, 140842.76, 
                                                                                                                                                                          137285.3, 135221.85, 135876.9, 134157.3994, 136594.2, 
                                                                                                                                                                          145706.03, 148210.311, 152517.724, 153594.542, 161765.89, 
                                                                                                                                                                          165363.8, 166815.81, 165929.6035, 169446.09, 171313.46, 
                                                                                                                                                                          173195.3, 177869.8, 181183.8524, 178400.24, 179260.2, 
                                                                                                                                                                          181955.21, 185101.85, 187807.85, 189018.71, 193211.19, 
                                                                                                                                                                          195934.7, 201605.8, 201741.19, 203898.05, 207591.75, 
                                                                                                                                                                          212215.7, 216120.09, 219355.15, 225603.6, 226774.45, 
                                                                                                                                                                          235955.42, 243532.247, 242824.77, 243911.78, 243028.6, 
                                                                                                                                                                          241872.3, 241450.8, 242606.17, 242283.75, 242585.29, 
                                                                                                                                                                          243305.19, 243570.27, 243752.23, 243628.5275, 236483.503, 
                                                                                                                                                                          236862.2976, 234998.8202, 85587.6273, 90329.4028, 98084.0031, 
                                                                                                                                                                          101116.0951, 110157.1971, 117556.2992, 117412.7424, 114860.61, 
                                                                                                                                                                          106454.29, 101066.96, 97814.5, 94004.29, 90871.3, 89188, 
                                                                                                                                                                          83911.2, 81276.2, 80080.1, 75965.452, 75629.3, 65319.3, 
                                                                                                                                                                          59125.553, 54647.032, 51879.281, 51475.164, 47480.287, 
                                                                                                                                                                          43544.349, 41887.089, 38259.782, 41399.896, 40983.218, 
                                                                                                                                                                          38502.49, 36067.55, 35259.5, 31695.19, 26719, 25091.146, 
                                                                                                                                                                          21508.7, 23826.2, 31062.812, 30547.462, 29159.056, 26447.31, 
                                                                                                                                                                          22515.3, 18843.11, 16533.7005, 11553.24, 11722.33, 16326.86, 
                                                                                                                                                                          16176.5, 21532.0955, 25186.62, 29758.8, 33564.69, 30937.38, 
                                                                                                                                                                          33634.05, 37739.51, 38942.78, 41252.69, 40955.9, 46485.13, 
                                                                                                                                                                          51499.1, 52498.96, 50935.2, 51230, 50188.29, 52316.6, 
                                                                                                                                                                          54063.23, 53817.89, 50574.037, 57101.11, 61854.2, 64425.91, 
                                                                                                                                                                          64075.22, 65591.63, 66286.69, 67931.3, 68882.1, 68711.36, 
                                                                                                                                                                          68553.3, 68240.53, 70929.8645, 78673.7992, 82399.9026, 
                                                                                                                                                                          85587.6273), .Dim = c(84L, 2L)))), class = c("XY", "MULTIPOLYGON", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_MULTIPOLYGON", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 134157.3994, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ymin = 11553.24, xmax = 454039.03, ymax = 537135.9959), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           input = "OSGB 1936 / British National Grid", wkt = "PROJCRS[\"OSGB 1936 / British National Grid\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"OSGB 1936\",\n        DATUM[\"OSGB 1936\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"Airy 1830\",6377563.396,299.3249646,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4277]],\n    CONVERSION[\"British National Grid\",\n        METHOD[\"Transverse Mercator\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9807]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",49,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",-2,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Scale factor at natural origin\",0.9996012717,\n            SCALEUNIT[\"unity\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8805]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",400000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",-100000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"(E)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"(N)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Engineering survey, topographic mapping.\"],\n        AREA[\"United Kingdom (UK) - offshore to boundary of UKCS within 49Â°45'N to 61Â°N and 9Â°W to 2Â°E; onshore Great Britain (England, Wales and Scotland). Isle of Man onshore.\"],\n        BBOX[49.75,-9,61.01,2.01]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",27700]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")


View(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A call of `sf::st_as_sf()` on your data object should suffice.

Consider this code:

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)

data_sf <- data %>% 
  st_as_sf()


tm_shape(data_sf) + tm_polygons(col = "lad19nm")
```

[image]

Comment: I am glad it does! And a personal observation - the easily recognizable shape of Cornwall, with added Hartlepool (of all places) makes for a really weird map 